# GeoJSON to PostgreSQL using ogr2ogr ERROR: Failed to create directory...for shapefile datastore

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr, import

I am using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) to import [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) to a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database and have used the following format with no error for more than half of the files:

```
ogr2ogr -nln schema.layer -append -progress PG:"dbname='mydb' host='localhost' user='postgres' port='5432' password='mypw'" "path\to\geojson"
```

Then, I followed the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596301/how-to-change-postgresql-data-directory) to change my data directory to an external drive, due to storage issues. It worked perfectly and all of the data is there and correct, but now when I try to run the exact same line to create each of the rest of the layers, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR 1: Failed to create directory PG:dbname='mydb' host='localhost' user='postgres' port='5432' password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for shapefile datastore.
ERROR 1: ESRI Shapefile driver failed to create PG:dbname='mydb' host='localhost' user='postgres' port='5432' password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I tried moving it back to my local drive, and get the same errors. Also restarted machine, tried importing a small shp, and importing to a brand new db, all the same errors.

Comment: Does GDAL find your database with ogrinfo `ogrinfo PG:"dbname='mydb' host='localhost' user='postgres' port='5432' password='mypw'"`? Does including the driver name `-of PostgreSQL` help with your original command?

Comment: I added -f PostgreSQL at the beginning and got: ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'. And it did not find the database (Unable to open datasource 'PG.....' with the following drivers")

Comment: It seems that for some reason you have lost your PostgreSQL/PostGIS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#postgresql-postgis from your GDAL installation. You can confirm it with `ogrinfo --format PostgreSQL`. If that is the case you must fix the GDAL installation.

Comment: UPDATE: It is now working in the OSGeo4W shell but I'll try to fix GDAL so that the normal cmd prompt can access the driver. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot run GDAL programs from the normal cmd prompt if you have not set some environmental variables. And OSGeo4W shell is just a command prompt with a bunch of environmental variables. But if you want to avoid using OSGeo4W for some reason, check the env variables with `SET`. At least you must set GDAL_DATA.

Comment: Please, specify your tool (ogr2ogr) version, database (postgres/postgis) version and operating system so that other people can help you.